# Workflow question: How to Write Memo's in Page Panel in Adobe InDesign?

Tags: adobe-indesign, page-layout, workflow, indesign-scripting, layout

When using Adobe InDesign, you `Pages` panel shows you all the pages of your document. But sometimes those pages look similar from the thumbnails (see printscreen below) and you can't really tell which page holds which content.

**I would like to write a 1 word memo near each page, making clear whats what.**

Example of words next to the page numbers, like: `Cover` , `Prologue` and  `Concept`  .
Is there a way to write such memos next to the page numbers?
(without altering the page numbers, sections etc)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think that is rather impossible. However, what you can do, is to add some colored labels to the pages with similar content. You can find it under the 'Page Attributes' of 'Pages' palette ('Main Menu->Window->Pages').

[image]

[image]